# COUNT(id) будет быстрее?

Tags: php, mysqli

Что будет быстрее?

```
$i = $DB->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `table`")->fetch_assoc();
```

или

```
$i = $DB->query("SELECT id FROM `table`")->num_rows;
```

?

Comment: Через SQL 100% будет быстрее

Answer (score 2):

Первый вариант будет быстрее т.к. не нужно тратить время на запихивание всех строк в ответ. RAM опятьже не пострадает.